# Terminating generator expression

Tags: python, generator

I'm having a mental block, is there a usual python 1-liner for terminating a list comprehension or genex based on some condition?  Example usage:

```
def primes():
  # yields forever e.g. 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13 ... 

[p for p in primes() if p < 10]
# will never terminate, and will go onto infinite loop consuming primes()

[p for p in primes() while p < 10]
# should return [2, 3, 5, 7], and consumed 5 items from my generator
```

I know about `itertools` consume, `islice`, but those guys require you to know how many items you want to consume in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.takewhile`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile):

```
itertools.takewhile(lambda x: x < 10, primes())
```

or… if you want to avoid lambda:

```
itertools.takewhile((10.).__gt__, primes())
```

Comment: facepalm .. I literally remembered that one the instant I posted my question.  Is there a way to avoid the lambda?

Comment: @wim - yes, there is, but it is not a very clear way.