# Short-circuiting list comprehensions

Tags: python, list-comprehension, generator-expression

On several occasions I've wanted python syntax for short-circuiting list comprehensions or generator expressions.

Here is a simple list comprehension, and the equivalent for loop in python:

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 'potato', 4, 5]
[x for x in my_list if x != 'potato']

result = []
for element in my_list:
    if element != 'potato':
        result.append(element)
```

There isn't support in the language for a comprehension which short-circuits.   Proposed syntax, and equivalent for loop in python:

```
[x for x in my_list while x != 'potato']
# --> [1, 2, 3]

result = []
for element in my_list:
    if element != 'potato':
        result.append(element)
    else:
        break
```

It should work with arbitrary iterables, including infinite sequences, and be extendible to generator expression syntax.  I am aware of `list(itertools.takewhile(lambda x: x != 'potato'), my_list)` as an option, but:

- it's not particularly pythonic - not as readable as a while comprehension
- it probably can't be as efficient or fast as a CPython comprehension
- it requires an additional step to transform the output, whereas that can be put into a comprehension directly, e.g. `[x.lower() for x in mylist]`
- even the [original author doesn't seem to like it much](http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/753516-fate-itertools-dropwhile-itertools-takewhile).

My question is, was there any theoretical wrinkle about why it's not a good idea to extend the grammar to this use case, or is it just not possible because python dev think it would be rarely useful?  It seems like a simple addition to the language, and a useful feature, but I'm probably overlooking some hidden subtleties or complications.

Related:  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5505891/674039) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15408933/674039)

Comment: `result = []; any(x=='potato' or result.append(x) for x in my_list)`. Hmm...no I think this is worse than takewhile :)

Comment: I think you are more likely to get a good answer in the [python-dev](http://mail.python.org/mailman/listinfo/python-dev) mailing list.

Comment: @gnibbler: you just implemented `filterfalse`, OP wants to stop all appending after first 'potato' is found. Try: `found = []; result = []; any(x=='potato' and not found.append(x) or result.append(x) if not found else None for x in my_list)`

Comment: Another syntax suggestion: `[x if x != 'potato' else break for x in my_list]`

Comment: @gnibbler's and my initial code golf comments are non-short-circuiting, though.

Comment: @PaulMcGuire, `any` shortcircuits it

Comment: @gnibbler - Doh! Thank you. (either too much or not enough coffee today)

Comment: `list(iter(iter(my_list).next, "potato"))` sounds funny when you say it out loud

Comment: @gnibbler the discussion in the mailing list contains some tricks you'll probably like.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Turns out, as @Paul McGuire noted, that it had been proposed in [PEP 3142](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3142/) and got [rejected](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2013-May/126136.html) by Guido:

> I didn't know there was a PEP for that. I hereby reject it. No point
> wasting more time on it.

He doesn't give explanations, though. In the mailing list, some of the points against it are:

- "[comprehension are] a carefully designed 1 to 1 transformation between multiple nested statements and a single expression.  But this proposal ignores and breaks that. ([here](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2009-January/085269.html))." That is, the `while` keyword does not correspond to a `while` in the explicit loop - it is only a `break` there.
- "It makes Python harder to learn because it adds one more thing to learn." (cited [here](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2009-January/085259.html))
- It adds another difference between generator expressions and list-comprehension. Seems like adding this syntax to list comprehension too is absolutely out of the question.

I think one basic difference from the usual list comprehension is that `while` is inherently imperative, not declarative. It depends and dictates an order of execution, which is not guaranteed by the language (AFAIK). I guess this is the reason it is not included in Haskell's comprehensions, from which Python stole the idea.

Of course, generator expressions do have direction<s>, but their elements may be precomputed - again, AFAIK</s>. The PEP mentioned did propose it *only* for generator expressions - which makes some sense.

Of course, Python *is* an imperative language anyway, but it will raise problems.

What about choosing out of a non-ordered collection?

```
[x for x in {1,2,3} while x!=2]
```

You don't have it in simple `for` loops too, but that's something you can't enforce by the language. `takewhile` answers this question, but it is an arbitrary answer.

---

One last point, note that for consistency you will want support for `dropwhile`. something like

```
[x for x in my_list from x != 'potato']
```

Which is even less related to the equivalent `for` construct, and this time it is not possibly short circuit if `my_list` is just an iterable.

Comment: You can just as easily write the for loop version as `for x in my_set:...` This doesn't make much sense to do anything useful either.

Comment: I think the absence of the `dropwhile` option without introducing a new keyword (like "after" in `[x for x in my_list after x=='potato']`) has been one of the hurdles to adoption, but I really like the idea - unfortunately, it has already been submitted as PEP 3142 (http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3142/) and rejected.

Comment: @gnibbler I referred to it explicitly, although not in a clear way: it is an arbitrary answer, which is better be avoided by the language. In a `for` loop there's simply no real way to restrict it.

Comment: and @PaulMcGuire, what's wrong with `from`?

Comment: @Elazar - would you need to say `[x for x in my_list from x == 'potato']`? To my ears, this would include the 'potato' entry, not just everything after 'potato'. If you really meant "!= 'potato'", then this is even more confusing to me, since entries before 'potato' are also not equal to 'potato'. Why was the PEP rejected? Check archived discussion on Python dev list (http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/).

Comment: So it was proposed years ago, interesting!  Guido must have been having a bad day, his response was a little brash.  I like your dropwhile syntax, that's a very elegant use of an existing keyword.

Comment: @wim but one that has absolutely no relation with its current meaning. - simply overloading it. (I am not saying I don't like the idea, personally).

Comment: Or somethng like `[x for x in iterable pass cond(x)]`

Comment: @wim even worse. I wouldn't understand what you mean.

Comment: I believe it only bothers you because `lambda x : x*x` is such an ugly and long way to say (x => x*x).

Comment: To be honest I have never used dropwhile, but I've needed takewhile a few times ..