# I wonder if it is possible that break in list comprehension with any method such as takewhile or others

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Here is a sample code to do it,

```
def func():
    return something

# I want to break the list comprehension at the first None.
# The walrus := is valid in Python 3.8
items = [r for _ in range(100) if (r := func()) is not None]
# else break?
```

I wonder if it is possible that break in list comprehension with any method, such as takewhile or others?

Comment: Something like this? `[z for z in takewhile(lambda x:x<3,[1,2,3,4,5])]` (using `takewhile` from `itertools`)

Comment: [Short-circuiting list comprehensions \[duplicate\]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16931214/674039)

Comment: @ScottHunter At that point, though, there's little reason to use a list comprehension instead of just passing the `takewhile` instance directly to `list`.

Comment: @chepner: I didn't say it was a good idea...

Comment: @ScottHunter Your sample really can break it, but I want to break it by some function return not the range(100)

Comment: @win It's not duplicate, Your link don't break it, and I want to break it with some function return not the range(100)

Comment: What about https://stackoverflow.com/a/7238861/674039

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List comprehension, no; it's basically syntactic sugar for `map` and `filter`. But `takewhile` and `map` will provide a suitable input for `list`, as you suspect.

```
items = list(takewhile(lambda x: x is not None, map(func, ...)))
```

Comment: items = list(takewhile(lambda x: x is not None, map(func, range(100)))), It works very  well. Thanks!